# jquery javascript passing value to html page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have the following value 'testValue' in my javascript file

```
$('#testValue').val(RestServices.getValueCovid(response, 'TESTVALUE'));
```

In the html file I have

```
<input name="testValue" id="testValue" />
```

This works and displays the value on the webpage but it is in an input box.

I want to display it just as plain text using `<p> <span> <div>` or whatever you suggest. The browser is IE8. I have tried getElementById and a few other ways but not working. Any suggestions welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create your page element, for example:

```
<span id="testValueText"></span>
```

Then set the text of that element much in the same way you set the value of the `<input>`:

```
$('#testValueText').text(RestServices.getValueCovid(response, 'TESTVALUE'));
```

A couple notes:

1. The `id` doesn't *have* to be what I specified here, it just has to be unique.  If you're getting rid of the `<input>` element then you can re-use the same `id` to make it simpler.
2. If you're using both elements then instead of fetching the value from `RestServices` twice, just fetch it once and store it in a variable.  Then use that variable to populate the two elements.

Comment: You legend. Sounds ridiculous but maybe lack of sleep it wouldn't work for me. That solved it. thank you